# How to catch a scroll event in GridView?

Tags: flutter

I need somehow to catch a scroll event in the GridView to update the `_length`  variable. So on scroll the `_length` is increasing and more content will be displayed in the GridView. How to make it?

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _length = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _contentGridView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _contentGridView() {
    return GridView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        itemCount: _length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          int i = getRandomId();
          return Image.network('https://i.pravatar.cc/1000?img=1');
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: you can add `ScrollController()`

Answer (score 1):

i belive you want `pagination`.

but according to your question answer will be something like , let me know something else you wanted.

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAppG extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppG> {
  late int _length;
  late ScrollController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _length = 10;
    controller = ScrollController();

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
          setState(() {
            _length += 3;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _contentGridView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _contentGridView() {
    return GridView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        itemCount: _length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 50,
            color: index % 3 == 0 ? Colors.cyanAccent : Colors.amberAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("$index"),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}


```
````

Comment: if the screen has an empty space (i.e. it has an empty space for more images) than controller does not work